# Make an array in Javascript with images from a folder

Tags: javascript, image, glob

I want to navigate through images from a folder with JS, and i want to make an array of the files in the folder. I can't figure how to do that...I want to make the array |var **images**| and get rid of the links that i have manualy put them there.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ranking Page</title>
<script language="Javascript">

var images = [
    "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=two",

    "http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=one"

    ];
var iIndex;
var iLen = images.length;

function fn_keydown(event) {
    var img = document.getElementById("wrapper").childNodes[1];
    if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        iIndex = (iIndex + 1) >= iLen ? 0 : iIndex + 1;
    } else if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        iIndex = (iIndex - 1) < 0 ? iLen-1 : iIndex - 1;
    }
    img.setAttribute("src", images[iIndex]);
}
window.onkeydown = fn_keydown;
window.onload = function() {
    iIndex = iLen;
    var vEvent = {
            keyCode : 39
        };
    fn_keydown(vEvent);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <img />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the source of your images ?
 Is there an api or a way to get file name ?

Comment: The images are on the same server. Yes, i can do something to rename the images from 1 to 100.jpg

Comment: You want an "array of the files" instead of the array of "links" (actually, URLs)? What do you mean by "file"? How should that be represented at runtime? What do you want to be able to do with such a file then? Read the binary contents? Link to them in the HTML?

Comment: Spot or create a pattern then loop through it. Renaming the images can be a solution (except if name matters). Or create a server script to serve images by position: `image.php?no=1 // return image n°1 in folder`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with JavaScript as it does not have access to a computer's file system. That is because JavaScript was designed with security in mind.

You need to use server side languages for this like asp or php.You would be able to access the filesystem then with the correct security permissions and build your javaScript array code on the server. When the page loads up the paths to your images will exist in the web page and then you can do what you want with them in your javaScript.